# Append list elements to list of list two elements at a time

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I want to iterate through a Python (3.8.5) list and append two items at a time into a list of lists.
The source list will always have an even number of elements.

example output:

```
[['a','b'],['c','d']['e','f'],['g','h']]
```

I have tried the range() function, for loop, while loop, etc. I am seeking an eloquent, efficient way to accomplish this. Below are two **incorrect** pathways I have explored using example data. **Thank you**.

```
letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k']
letter_pairs = []
count = 0

for i in range(2): 
    for letter in letters:
        letter_pairs.append([letter, letter])
```

```
while count < 2:
   for letter in letters:
       letter_pairs.append([letter, letter])
       count += 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use zip:

```
[list(x) for x in zip(letters[:-1:2], letters[1::2])]
```

Comment: My pleasure, Digfield :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use slices, with the `skip` argument for `range()`.

```
letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k']
letter_pairs = []

for i in range(0, len(letters), 2): 
    slice_to_append = letters[i:i+2]
    if len(slice_to_append) == 2: letter_pairs.append(slice_to_append)
```

Now `letter_pairs` is `[['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'], ['e', 'f'], ['g', 'h'], ['i', 'j']]`

Or, in a list-comprehension:

```
letter_pairs = [letters[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(letters), 2) if i < len(letters) - 1]
```

The `if i < len(letters) - 1` ensures that `letters[i:i+2]` always has two elements.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add two items at a time in lists, you can do this:

```py
letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k']
letter_pairs = []
try:
    for i in range(0, len(letters),2):
        letter_pairs.append([ letters[i], letters[i+1] ])
pass:
    pass # or you can append the last one if you want
```

What this does is it iterates over `letters`, two by two, each time taking the letter at the position and one after that position in lists and appending them to `letter_pairs`.

Answer (score 0):

```py
from itertools import zip_longest

letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k']
args = [iter(letters)] * 2
list(zip_longest(*args, fillvalue=None))
```

the output:

```
[('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd'), ('e', 'f'), ('g', 'h'), ('i', 'j'), ('k', None)]
```

Description:

Here we crate the iterator (so no additional memory allocation) over the letters list, then put it twice in a list (maybe a tuple or another iterable object), then using the `zip_longest` function from `itertools` module groups the elements in groups by 2. The Same you can easily make with groups of 3 or more elements - just replace `* 2` with the necessary number. Also `zip_longest` may be replaced with built-in `zip` function, but it'll failed if there are not enough elments in the list to group.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an iterator to achieve your need.

```py
iter_ = iter(letters)
while (a := next(iter_, None)) and (b := next(iter_, None)):
    letter_pairs.append([a, b])
if a: letter_pairs.append([a])
print(letter_pairs)
>>> [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'], ['e', 'f'], ['g', 'h'], ['i', 'j'], ['k']]
```

Answer (score 0):

**The source list will always have an even number of elements**, then the way you are using `range()` should work for you,

```
letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j']
list1= [letters[i:i+2] for i in range(0,len(letters),2)]
print(list1)
```

**Output:**

```
[['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'], ['e', 'f'], ['g', 'h'], ['i', 'j']]
```